# Airflow - Script changes the filename variable

Tags: python, airflow

I created a process in airflow where I need every 10min to export a new file from a SQL Server database and play to BigQuery! The generated file is a csv that automatically contains the filename with the processing date in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format.

When I go from step 1 (export) to step 2 (insert in BigQuery) the airflow relay again every script changes the file name variable name and the processing date is different from step 1!

Example:
Step1: test_20190624113656.csv
Step 2: test_20190624113705.csv

In that case I would like to keep the file name in the first step.

```
nm_arquivo = 'test_' + datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.csv'

def insert_bigquery(ds, **kwargs):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(project="project_name")
    dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset('test_dataset')
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField('id','INTEGER',mode='REQUIRED'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('sigla','STRING',mode='REQUIRED'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('nome_en','STRING',mode='REQUIRED'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('nome_pt','STRING',mode='REQUIRED'),
    ]   
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
    time_partitioning = bigquery.table.TimePartitioning()
    job_config.time_partitioning = time_partitioning
    job_config.clustering_fields = ["id", "sigla"]
    uri = "gs://bucket_name/"+nm_arquivo
    load_job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri,
        dataset_ref.table('bdb'),
        job_config=job_config
        )
    print('Starting job {}'.format(load_job.job_id))
    load_job.result()
    print('Job finished.')

#step1      
import_orders_op = MsSqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='import_orders',
    mssql_conn_id='mssql_conn',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='gcp_conn',
    sql="""select * from bdb""",
    bucket='bucket_name',
    filename=nm_arquivo,
    dag=dag) 

#step2
run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='insert_bigquery',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=insert_bigquery,
    dag=dag,
)

run_this.set_upstream(import_orders_op)
```

Comment: Could you share your insert_bigquery function ?
I think you should not use datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') but the ds_nodash variable since it will be constant

Comment: @GeorgesLorré, i edited the code...

Comment: Can you try using: 
`filename='test_{{ ts_nodash }}.csv'`
in both your steps ?

More info on the macros [here](https://airflow.apache.org/macros.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the execution time of the DAG.

You can use `{{ ts_nodash }}` Airflow macros. It formats the  `execution_date.isoformat()` (Example: `2018-01-01T00:00:00+00:00`) to remove `-` & `:`, example: `20180101T000000`. This macros can be used in any templated parameter.

For more information and a list of all the other available variables:

- https://airflow.apache.org/1.10.3/macros.html#default-variables
- Airflow Macros - https://airflow.apache.org/1.10.3/macros.html

Comment: the first step of the function was recognized, but in the second step of PythonOperator, it did not recognize this macro and failed again!

Comment: I only change this: nm_arquivo = 'test_{{ ts_nodash }}.csv' but in the second step the function tries to find test_{{ ts_nodash }}.csv and not the file test_20180101T000000.csv

Comment: I believe that only in PythonOperator does not work but in other functions the airflow worked without problems!

Comment: @FelipeFB You can use it in PythonOperator as `kwargs["ts_nodash"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a file to store the filename:

```py
import pickle

nm_arquivo = 'test_' + datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.csv'

#step 1
with open('filename.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(nm_arquivo, handle)

#step 2
with open('filename.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    nm_arquivo = pickle.load(handle)
```

Comment: I think I can not insert this into the Airflow function.